# iPhone Development: Grabbing selected/highlighted text on UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, selection

Greetings,

Please kindly advice on how possibly I can get the selected text on **UIWebVIew**.

I went on to search on how to deal with selected/highlighted text and found the following:

[Selection and Menu Management](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/EventHandling/EventHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH9-SW34)

> To copy or cut something in a view,
>   that “something” must be selected. It
>   can be a range of text, an image, a
>   URL, a color, or any other
>   representation of data, including
>   custom objects. To implement
>   copy-and-paste behavior in your custom
>   view, you must manage the selection of
>   objects in that view yourself. If the
>   user selects an object in the view by
>   making a certain touch gesture (for
>   example, a double-tap) you must handle
>   that event, internally ***record the
>   selection*** (and deselect any previous
>   selection), and perhaps visually
>   indicate the new selection in the
>   view. If it is possible for users to
>   select multiple objects in your view
>   for copy-cut-paste operations, you
>   must implement that multiple-selection
>   behavior.

And that's where I got lost. *"...record the selection"* - I'm not even sure how to represent a selection let alone recording it.

Any help is very much appreciated. ^^ Cheers!

Kind regards,
oonoo

Comment: That paragraph would seem to pertain to developers of custom views. You did not write UIWebView, so you probably don't need to worry about teaching it how to select text.

Comment: Hi NSD thanks for the response. You're right I'm not concerned about how the text is highlighted/selected because it already is supported, but I was wondering how, when a user highlights a text, I can retrieve that particular text.

Comment: @hi,Did you acchive it? i also working out for same....

Answer (score 17):

You can use [stringByEvaulatingJavaScriptFromString](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:) to get the currently selected text in a UIWebView.

```
NSString *selection = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString()"];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Selected Text" message:selection delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release], alert = nil;
```

Comment: i am not able to implement this code,when and how to call this method. can you provide any sample code please?

Comment: NSString *selection = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString()"];

Perfect code. Thanks for this.

Comment: @Kris Markel I am showing the PDF on UIWebView and select test but on menuItem action I am not getting the selected text here is my code:
`  
UIMenuItem *customMenuItem1 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Custom 1" action:@selector(customAction1:)];


-(void)customAction1:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Selected String : %@", [self SelectedStringGet]);
}

- (NSString *)SelectedStringGet{
    NSString *selection = [self.WV_Pdf stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString()"];
    return selection; `

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at using window.getSelection() in JavaScript. It will allow you to get the current text selection which you could then store in a global variable and access that variable via the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method on UIWebView. Unfortunately, I don't know of a way in iOS JavaScript to identify when the text selection has changed so instead use an interval to continuously check for that. I have actually done all this so I know it can work. In terms of storing the text selection ranges for later use as well as applying styles I would look into a JavaScript library named [rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/). I found it to be incredibly useful in creating highlighting jQuery plugin (that works on both the desktop and on iOS - not for Android though).