# get data from a ViewController to another ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm coding an app for ipad. I create a PopViewController as a popup menu and use the following statements in ThirdViewConroller when the user clicks on the actionButton.

```
// set UIPopupoverController   
-(IBAction)actionButton:(id)sender
{
  if([popupCtr isPopoverVisible])
  {
    [popupCtr dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

  }else
  {

    [popupCtr setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(500, 500)];
    [popupCtr presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny     animated:YES];

  }
}
```

**The ThirdViewController has a UIWebView. I want to pass the data that user selects words in the UIWebView to the PopViewController, then I can use the data by clicking the buttons in PopViewController.** Such as the buttons, Reply, Reply All, Forward, and Print, in the mail-app of ipad get data from the mail.

**How can I do it?**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: check this link. Did you mean that?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968872/iphone-development-grabbing-selected-highlighted-text-on-uiwebview

Comment: Do you want to pass value into another class ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want one object to be able to get or receive data from another object, you need a reference to that object. Normally one of the objects creates the other one. At that time you give it a reference so it can always call methods on the object.

Consider the objects "Boss" and "Worker"

- **Boss hires Worker.** (Boss object creates worker object)
- **Boss tells Worker he's the boss.** (Boss object calls method on Worker object and which assigns a reference to boss).
- **Boss remembers Worker.** (Boss object stores reference to Worker object in instance variable)
- <<<< time passes... Worker wants raise >>>
- **Worker asks Boss for raise.** (Worker object uses reference to Boss object and call method "askForRaise" on it.)
- <<<< time passes... Boss is sick of lazy Worker >>>
- **Boss fires Worker.** (Boss object uses instance variable of Worker object and calls method "fire" on it)

The concept for 3 objects is pretty much the same, you just need more references. Create, assign references, then go separate ways. Whenever they need to talk later you can use the references.