# Getting the selected text of a UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiwebview

I'm trying to access the currently selected text in a `UIWebView` using the following line of code:

```
NSString *highlighted = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection();"];
```

But it only returns an emtpy string. Any ideas about what I'm missing?

Comment: Nice question, answers to this question saved me from headache.. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with  this :

```
NSString * highlighted = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString()"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also stumbled upon this problem, and this is really frustrating. I don't exactly remember from where I got the solution, but it's the following; `getSelection()` returns a JavaScript object that cannot be converted to a string. You have to explicitly convert it to a string from the JavaScrtipt code:

```
NSString *highlighted = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString();"];
```

[See it in action.](https://github.com/H2CO3/ExplainIt/blob/master/ExplainIt.m)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help

```
NSString *selection = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString()"];
```

Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968872/iphone-development-grabbing-selected-highlighted-text-on-uiwebview) too

Comment: I guess you were the first one with the correct answer, so I'm going to mark this one correct. Thanks.

Comment: @fabian789: thanks for your comment. I think Maulik and H2CO3 answered first.

Comment: @MidhunMP thanks,I took the text by using this code but how can i store this text and reterive it whenever we open and read the page

Answer (score 1):

In swift: self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("window.getSelection().toString();")

The semicolon at the end of the Javascript is required, without this it did not work!

Answer (score 0):

Try this with swift:

```
// stringByEvaluatingJavaScript retunr optional string, hence use if-let block

if let selectedString = self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "window.getSelection().toString()") {
   print(selectedString - \(selectedString))
}
```